# R: storing regression models

Tags: r, loess

I am using multiple regression models to model a problem e.g. one for each day of the week. I want to store these in a data structure in R so I can call them when needed. As a minimal example of the problem, say I want to construct one for each value of `z`:

```
df = data.frame(z = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 10),
            x = rep.int(1:10, times = 2), 
            y = rep.int(10:1, times = 2))
```

Naively, I tried the following attempt:

```
dt = data.table(df)

v.type = unique(dt$z)
v.loess = numeric(0)

for(i in v.type)
  v.loess = c(v.loess, loess(y ~ x, data = dt[z==i]))

dt.loess = data.table(type = v.type, model = v.loess)
```

Given e.g. `type = a` and `x = 2.5`, the idea was then to run something like this:

```
predict(dt.loess[z == 'a', 'model', with = FALSE], newdata = 2.5)
```

This method fails utterly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am not in front of my PC. Can you pl check the `class` of model vector being passed into `predict` function?

Comment: shouldn't it be `for(i in v.type)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loess()` returns an S3 object of class `loess`. Internally these objects are represented as lists, what you can see if you call `str()` on them.

Now there are mainly two reasons why your solutions fails:

1. In the for loop, you concatenate these objects (read here lists) with `c()` which simply concatenates the list elements (or object fields) to one larger list, resulting in an invalid object of class `loess`. Then you try to save this list as column in your `data.table`.
2. I don't see why you would want to store the models in the end in a `data.table`, but I am almost sure, that this can't be done, since the column elements must be (as far as I remember) atomic vectors or lists. I'd rather store the models in a named list and leave them there.

---

#### Solution using base R

```
model <- list()
for( i in unique(dt$z) ){
  model[[i]] <- loess(y ~ x, data = dt[ z==i ] )
}
```

#### Solution using plyr

```
library("plyr")
model <- dlply( df, "z", function(data){
  loess( y ~ x, data = data )
} )
```

Or even shorter:

```
library("plyr")
model <- dlply( df, "z", loess, formula = quote(y ~ x) )
```

The latter two solutions can be applied on both: `data.table` and `data.frame`, but you don't take any advantages of the `data.table` in this case. So you have to decide what is faster and less error-prone in the end.

---

In all three cases you can call

```
predict( model[["a"]], newdata = 2.5)
[1] 8.5
```

Comment: Thanks not only for the answer, but also an extremely illuminating and helpful explanation of why mine was so wrong.

Comment: This works with the example data set, however all approaches above lead to the following error with my actual data set: `Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  : invalid 'x'`. Are there 'usual culprits' for such an error message of is this something that can only be answered by looking at my actual data set?

Comment: Personally, I don't know about *usual* culprits, but it would be very helpful if you could at least try to pin down the problem to the subset of the `data.frame` for which the error is thrown. Maybe by simply printing `unique(data$z)` in the `plyr` function or `i` in the `for` loop. Does the subset look odd?

Comment: problem solved. some rogue `NA`'s had crept in. Thanks for your help Beasterfield.

Answer (score 2):

For one, using `c` to combine the results is giving funny results; better to fill up a list directly.  For another, using `data.table` to get the results out is tricky; I'm not a `data.table` expert, so I would just use the results directly from the list.

```
v.type = unique(df$z)
v.loess = list()
for(i in v.type) {
  v.loess[[i]] <- loess(y ~ x, data = df[df$z==i,])
}
predict(v.loess$a, newdata=2.5)
predict(v.loess$b, newdata=2.5)
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer was not posted when I started writing mine. Now it looks as if I just have copied yours :-/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Aaron,